# Node memory issues with Socket.io, how to collect and debug heap snapshots? How to do load tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, socket.io

I am having much trouble debugging my node app. I am using the [Usage](https://www.npmjs.org/package/usage) package to monitor memory like this:

```
var usage = require('usage');

module.exports = function (io, app, db) {

  //every 3 seconds
  new CronJob('*/3 * * * * *', function() {

      var pid = process.pid;
      usage.lookup(pid, function(err, result) {
        io.sockets.emit('usage', result);
      });

  }):

};
```

Just after I start the app $ nodemon app.js it has about 80 megabytes footprint. With almost every refresh it slowly increases the memory usage, I got to about 160 megabytes (how can I automate this process? I cannot hit refresh button forever). Sometimes it would lower the memory usage but only slightly.

I also found out, that emitting large amount of data (2 MG) with Socket.io like this:

```
socket.emit(emitString, seasonsArray);
```

will cause memory to change randomly between about 150, 250, 350 MG and its only with manually refreshing the browser tab. I don't plan to always send this amount of data to every user but its still worrying.

I decided to try found out why Socket.io cause so large memory usage. Limiting transports won't help.

```
io.set('transports', ['jsonp-polling',
                      'polling']);
```

I was trying to find a better way to look into memory usage. I installed the [node-webkit-agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent) but the heap snapshots I am able to collect are only about 20 MG so I think it doesn't work for me. Using it without nodemon won't help.

```
var agent = require('webkit-devtools-agent');
agent.start();
```

When I try to use it Node logs:

```
Timeline.supportsFrameInstrumentation is not implemented
Timeline.canMonitorMainThread is not implemented
CSS.getSupportedCSSProperties is not implemented
Network.enable is not implemented
Network.enable is not implemented
Page.getResourceTree is not implemented
CSS.enable is not implemented
Database.enable is not implemented
DOMStorage.enable is not implemented
```

So my questions are:

How can I automate page refreshes so I can test for how my app responds to load and if there are any memory leaks?

Why Socket.io causes my app footprint to jump randomly for even about 250 MG up?

And finally how should I debug and collect proper heap snapshots of my app? What does the community use?

Node version I use is 0.10.26, Socket.io is 1.1.0, express is 3.4.8. Please help :)

Comment: I used [v8 profiler](https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-profiler) recently to debug a memory issue.

Comment: How?? I can't use it with node-inspector. I can't see profiles tab.

Comment: I have installed heapdump, taken and loaded a snapshot to dev tools. They are about 20 MB. When my node process in OS is about 150 MB and Usage package keeps logging similar values. Why?

Comment: Take a look at [this discussion]( https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-profiler/issues/45 ). The author explained how to load the snapshot into chrome

Comment: try disabling websocket protocol to narrow the scope of cause.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use selenium to automate browsers. I prefer to use [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor), which is an abstraction on top of Selenium perfect for E2E testing of angular applications.
   In protractor/selenium you can run almost unlimited number of browser instances at once and have them load up your app and perform any task a user would.
   This is called e2e testing.
   What you probably want is to start with regular unit testing-socket.io has [node client](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io-client), so just use that and you can open as many connections as you would like from your unit test. Your backend won't know the difference between node client and browser client.
2. 250MB is not normal for socket.io 1.1.0. I suspect that you are probably leaking memory in some loop which loops a lot. Try tracking it down with https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch It is very easy to create memory leak in JS, especially when using events or any other pattern which expects programmer to clean up manually after himself.
   Older version of socket.io did indeed leak little bit, but they fixed that in 1.0.0 
   Big memory consumption is not abnormal for node. Garbage collection is very expensive operation, so if you have free memory V8 rather just creates more garbage rather than frozing your whole process for few precious miliseconds.
3. For debugging node.js, most people use [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)
4. one afterthought- when limiting transports, try only websocket. Theoretically Websocket should be the least memmory hungry transport.

Comment: Thanks for help. Node-inspector won't let me see profiles tab and I cannot inspect snapshots. I have installed heapdump, taken and loaded a snapshot to dev tools. They are about 20 MB. When my node process in OS is about 150 MB and Usage package keeps logging similar values. Why?